# How to design an android app for Android TV in eclipse? My design differs when i run in android TV

Tags: android

I have developed an app for Android TV in eclipse, but when i run it on android TV of Hp brand. Its design get disturbed. but it appears right on eclipse. What is missing or i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're running an Android TV app, pick the activity you want and make sure it's marked as the LEANBACK LAUNCHER activity in the manifest.

Find out more here: http://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/start.html

Comment: thanks @Felker for reply. What if all activities are of TV app, will we have to mark leanback launcher to every activity?

and also if we want my button size increases with respect to screen size. What to do?

Comment: Hey mariah. Here's a few things about TV activities:
* They will, by default, work exactly like the phone app. You only need to set which activity opens when the app is launched on a TV.
* To change the UI, you can use specific resource directories. Your layouts can go in `layout` while TV layouts go in `layout-television` with the same name. The OS will pick the best fitting layout
* If you don't have a TV layout for a given item, it'll use the default layout by that name
* Use the styles.xml in `values` and `values-television` for even more nuanced control over UI elements

Comment: oh thank you for your help. That was really helpful information.